# How can I model two separate composite keys for the same table in Cassandra 1.2?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql3

My use case is as follows: I have to store and query data from multiple third-party sources. The only predefined schema knowledge I have is that it consists of Entity-Attribute-Value tuples with an additional Source component: `(E, A, V, S)`. I do not know in advance which attributes will be present (so using the actual attributes themselves as columns is a problematic). The combination `(E,A,V)` must be unique, and I therefore thought using that as the composite key would be the best way to model this, so we get this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
       E text,
       A text,
       V text,
       S text,
       PRIMARY KEY(E, A, V)
);
```

This will enable me to ask queries like:

- given E, show all attributes A and values V and the sources S in which they occur
- given E and A, give all V.

The plan is to create mirrors of this table with differently ordered compound keys so that I can also answer queries of the form:

- given A, show all entities E and values V.
- given S, show all E, A, V tuples.

and so on and so forth (effectively, the mirror tables play the role of indexes, and to get full indexing I will need 6 copies of effectively the same data - not sure about the scalability of that approach yet, but that's a separate question I guess).

So far so good, however, the part I'm struggling with is this: `V` is in fact an object in its own right, with multiple properties. If this were a relational model, I would have `V` be a foreign key field pointing to a relation that maps its `id` to, for example, a `type` field and a `value` field. But getting rid of foreign keys (and the joins that go with them) is more or less the point of the BigTable approach I guess, so I'm looking for a way to incorporate this into my table `t1`.

Of course, I could do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
       E text,
       A text,
       V_id text,
       S text,
       V_type text,
       V_value text,
       PRIMARY KEY(E, A, V_id)
);
```

But the problem I see is that this fails to capture the (inverse-)functional relation between `V`'s id, type and value: with the above table, I could get, for example:

```
 E  | A  | V_id | V_type | V_value
 ---+----+------+--------+--------
 a1 | b1 |    1 | X      | foo
 a1 | b1 |    2 | X      | foo
 a1 | b2 |    1 | Y      | bar
```

While I want to be able to ensure that given a `V_id`, type and value are unique, and vice versa. I guess what I'm after is what in the older Cassandra versions would be a nested super column, but I'm trying to achieve what I need with CQL3.

I briefly looked into collection types, but that doesn't quite seem to fit my use case.

Can anyone suggest a better way to model this, keeping in mind that ideally, I'd like to be able to retrieve `(E, A, V)` and in as few queries as possible? Or am I just overthinking it and is the approach as I currently have it in fact fine (I can of course try and ensure uniqueness at the application level)?

Comment: What about `d`? You say you want to get `(a, b, c_type, c_value)`, so where does `d` fit in? I think your question would be much easier to answer if you just told us what `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` actually were. As it is it's a bit too abstract.

Comment: @Theo I have modified the question to make it more concrete, hope this makes it clearer what I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeen, consider using map for V. See http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/cql_cli/using/collections
Map, list, set types were introduced to avoid situations like encoding/decoding key-value pairs into and from string/byte arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could denormalize t1 and create a new table where you could store attributes for a particular v_id. This way you could achieve the join equivalent of SQL. Assuming v_id is unique, your new table could have the following structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE t2 (
        V_id text PRIMARY KEY,
        type text,
        value text,
    );
```

There is a very good read on mapping SQL operations to Cassandra : http://maxgrinev.com/2010/07/12/do-you-really-need-sql-to-do-it-all-in-cassandra/[enter link description here](http://maxgrinev.com/2010/07/12/do-you-really-need-sql-to-do-it-all-in-cassandra/)

Comment: I thought of doing this, but I was put off by the idea that essentially, it means doing two queries: one to retrieve `E, A, V_id`, and then a second query to retrieve `V_type, V_value` for the given `V_id`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: well yes ! you will be doing two queries this way but it will get you a clean structure that would be easy to work with.

Comment: bw with your current structure, if you want to get unique values, you need to re consider you primary keys. since cassandra would create a new entry when ever there is a change in a variable that is part of the primary key and will over-write entries that have the same primary keys(all parts of the primary key).  In your case you are getting duplicate v_type and v_value because A is different for both of them which is part of the primary key.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Food for thought!